# What is touch_pad_get_status() supposed to return?

Tags: functions

What I want to do:
I have 7 touch buttons on my board (ESP32 TTGO T-Display) and I want to attach interrupts to everyone, calling the same function.
In this function I would like to use touch_pad_get_status() or other to get which button was touched. Then a switch case would do the rest.

What I'm facing:
This code

```
  Serial.print("Button ");
  uint32_t touch = touch_pad_get_status();
  Serial.println(String(touch));
```

always returns 0, no matter what.

What I've tried:
Including this part of code to the setup

```
  touch_pad_init();
  touch_pad_set_fsm_mode(TOUCH_FSM_MODE_TIMER); //tried the SW MODE too
  touch_pad_io_init(TOUCH_PAD_GPIO15_CHANNEL);
```

But nothing seem to work. I don't want to make 7 different functions...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried the example code that is included with the library?

Comment: @jsotola yes, but none uses this function. There was one example that was similar to this application, but it implemented one function for each button :(

Comment: See: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/touch_pad.html

See part 'Touch Detection' and 'Touch Triggered Interrupts'.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers You're saying the touchAttachInterrupt(...) cannot be used in this scenario? Also I don't know what a intr_handler_t is, there isn't any example online.

Comment: I don't know exactly, however https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/6e77694/examples/peripherals/touch_pad_interrupt seems to be an example.

Comment: `touch_pad_get_status()` is supposed to be used from within a touch interrupt. Full documentation: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/touch_pad.html

Comment: Thank you all, I'll post an answer to my own question as now I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out from people in the comments, things need to be different.
If you use the function `touchAttachInterrupt`, things are a bit simpler.
The example that comes with the ESP32 library is enough to make you understand.

If you want to do what I did, this is how:

```
  touch_pad_init();
  touch_pad_set_fsm_mode(TOUCH_FSM_MODE_TIMER);
  touch_pad_config(TOUCH_PAD_GPIO2_CHANNEL, 500);
  touch_pad_config(TOUCH_PAD_GPIO15_CHANNEL, 500);
  touch_pad_config(TOUCH_PAD_GPIO13_CHANNEL, 500);
  touch_pad_isr_register(TouchButton, NULL);
  touch_pad_intr_enable();
```

Put this code in the `setup()`. Of course needs the `init()`, but also needs to be set to timer mode, or otherwise you're going to need to `start()` probably.
The `config()` is to configure the pin as an interrupt. I've set 500 in the threshold because the readings of `touch_pad_read()` told me it went from 800 untouched to 50 touched, so the midterm I chose 500.
`isr_register` is the function that tells to call `TouchButton()`, with `NULL` as argument to it.

```
void TouchButton(void *arg)
{
  uint32_t touch = touch_pad_get_status();
  touch_pad_clear_status();
  Serial.print("Button ");
  Serial.println(String(touch));
}
```

This is the declaration of the callback function I've done. It should be noted that `clear_status()` should be called as soon as possible after the `get_status()`, preventing the system from panicking (that's the name). You'll also see in the serial monitor that each button represents a power of 2. That's because the `get_status()` returns the pin mask in binary. So just do something similar to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < TOUCH_PAD_MAX; i++) {
    if ((pad_intr >> i) & 0x01) {
        s_pad_activated[i] = true;
    }
}
```

and you'll get a vector of which one was pressed.

Comment: Upvoted for the detailed answer and helping others.

Comment: And one give you a little nudge over the [comment everywhere](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) threshold sooner rather than later.  In a few days you'll be able to mark your own answer as accepted.